# Form inheriting from another form will not open if the namespace does not match the path

Tags: c#, forms, inheritance, namespaces, designer

I have an issue where I have a form inherited from a base control within my companies base Framework.

The base control in this is case called `PlugInBase` and is inherited from the standard `System.UserControl`.
The `namespace` has to be fixed and does not match the path of the assembly.
The `namespace` is `namespace Omitec.ThreeG.Runtime.Portal.PlugIns` but the path is `Omitec.ThreeG.Runtime.Portal.WindowsNative.PlugInBase`.

If I try to open the form based on `PlugInBase` I get the standard `Exception` screen saying that the designer could not be shown as `Omitec.ThreeG.Runtime.Portal.PlugInBase` could not be loaded.

Yet if I change the `namespace` in `PlugInBase` to match the path it opens no bother.

The other weird thing is only some of the engineers in our office have this error. Other's do not.

After further investigation it's definitely an issue with the inherited controls namespace not matching the file path.

Is there some setting that strictly enforces the lookup of the namespace? As I mentioned earlier some of the developers in the office do not have this issue with the exact same section of code. that

As the framework is shared code I can not change the `namespace` from the standard.

This has been driving me mad for a while now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio does this on occasion.

Keep in mind that the designer does actually run the form's constructor to generate the designer. If there is something in there that may throw this exception it could be your cause.

Since the program is not actually running there is room for design time errors.

If that is not the problem, the other way i have fixed it is to close all open designers. Clean Solution, Build, then open the designer again. Sometimes i have to add an additional step of closing visual studio if it has been open for a while.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I've tried that multiple times.